# Nature of the Orville Shuttles' cloak

Tags: technology, the-orville

In a few episodes of The Orville, namely "Majority Rule" and "Mad Idolatry", we see that the Orville's shuttle are equipped with a cloaking device of sorts (referred to simply as "cloak" by Orville crew members). I find this somewhat unusual given that we never see this technology on larger ships.

Also, since the shuttles' cloak was only used to hide from primitive cultures (one at 21st-century tech, and one at bronze age-level tech), it makes me wonder whether this cloak renders the shuttle fully sensor-hidden, or if it's more of a simple "active camouflage" rendering it invisible to the visible light spectrum.

Are there any sources (from behind-the-scenes documentaries, interviews, etc) indicating what the limitations of the cloak is; and whether the Orville itself is similarly provisioned, or if this can only be done on a smaller scale?

Comment: I don't know if there's a good answer to this, but I'd be curious.  They've cloaked shuttles to try to avoid the Krill (nothing left but the fishes episode).   Didn't work cause the Krill shot paint into space - LOL.  But it does seem like a cloak for larger ships could be useful.  Maybe they'll address that in season 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Orville Wiki](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/Cloaking_device), cloaking devices are used on *all* Union spacecraft, and that they're specifically designed to bend light around the vessel, which would hide it from visual detection and any ambient light/radiation-based sensing equipment, but potentially not from those looking for gravitational anomalies, waste energy output/exhaust, or other effects *generated* by the cloaked ship.

We still mainly see it used with shuttles (both the old style and the new Season 3 shuttle design) against primitive civilizations, including [Spoiler for S3E6: "Twice in a Lifetime"]:

> Earth in 2025 AD

However, we also see it against more advanced civilizations, including [Spoiler for S3E8: "Midnight Blue"]:

> A secret Moclan base. In this situation, it's worth noting that the mission was improvised and the shuttle presumably wasn't specially modified or upgraded for this case.

> However, its also unknown what detection capabilities the base had; advanced sensor equipment may have been deemed unnecessary for a base no one is supposed to know about; perhaps the Moclans are just better with weapons systems than sensors or cloak countermeasures; or possibly, the scans necessary to detect cloaked vessels aren't performed as often as light-based scans.

**UPDATE:**

In S3E9: "Domino" a shuttle is cloaked against enemy ships, presumably similar technologically to the Planetary Union. [Spoiler for S3E9: "Domino"]:

> The enemy ships consist of Krill and Moclan fighters.

The cloak is used not so much to evade detection altogether - it is, in fact, being escorted by non-cloaked *pterodon* fighters - but rather to confound the enemy ships' weapon targeting systems.

Answer (score 5):

The implication on the show is that the cloak is active camouflage that would be useless against technologically-equivalent enemies. In the episode "Command Performance", the nearest thing to a ship's cloak is seen when Isaac modifies tech recovered from the Calivon to project a holographic image of a Calivon ship around the *Orville*.

Answer (score 0):

Still, they visit a 21th century-civilization, a planet with a lot in common with Earth’s history. The technological presentation suggests they would have developed at least some kind of modern radar systems. Four options to consider

1. They also have a passive stealth composition on their shuttle to fool radar.
2. They avoided radar by using a gap.
3. The cloack also protects against active scanning and radar.
4. This civilization doesn’t use radar extensivly for they never felt the need for it like our Cold War and post Cold War Earth does.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This seems like nice informed speculation, which is good when we have no evidence. However, so you are aware here we prefer answers rooted in evidence, if you have any I would encourage you to [edit] it in.